# copper plate came with raspberry pi

Tags: hardware

I was wondering I got two heat sinks and a copper plate what the hell is the copper plate for ? When I bought the raspberry PI 2 it came with green and black and copper.  Green was the big heat sink and the black small and copper was a plate

Comment: A picture and the URL for the part you are asking about would help. Please edit your question and add these details.

Comment: ...look under the PCB and at the pictures in http://www.banggood.com/-p-975867.html may help too...

Comment: I have a little pile of those heatsinks now, I've been thinking of making them into earrings or something. I'll need a few 1/2" square piercings though...

Answer (score 5):

There is exactly a picture showing how to use the coper plate from the link you given. It seems it's placed under the CPU at the back of the board, and be careful there is a plastic plate between the pins and the copper plate.
According to Raspberry Pi Foundation, [you don't need a heatsink](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#performanceHeatsink), if you use it normally, that is not overclocking. So I think it will be fine if you don't use it.
[image]